# Как запустить Activity находящееся в папке с тестами?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-testing

Есть `Activity`, которое лежит в папке с тестами (не юнит, а инструментальные androidTest). Хочу запустить это `Activity` в рамках теста, чтобы оно было только там и нигде больше. Проблема в том, что это активити необходимо указать в манифесте приложения, но родной манифест файл не видит пути до этой активити, которая лежит в папке с тестами. Если создать второй манифест и положить внутрь папки `androidTest` то этот манифест просто проигнорируется.
Как быть?

По сути, хочу запустить отдельно фрагмент приложения. Но чтобы это сделать, нужна активити. Хочу создать активити в папке с тестами и использовать ее как стартовый компонент для фрагмента.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно перенести вашу тестовую активити и манифест с ней например в debug вариант сборки. Либо создать для это отдельный вариант сборки и запускать тесты на нем если debug не подходит по каким то причинам. Манифесты из папок с тестами не объединяются с основным, то есть действительно игнорируются.